# Chernoff style bounds for Poisson distribution

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

I [read](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X12004827) today that

> for a Poisson distributed random variable $Z$ with expectation $\mathbb E(Z) = \lambda$,
>   $$P
> (Z \ge \lambda +t) \le \exp\left( -\frac {t^2}{2(\lambda + t/3)} \right).
> $$

This is true if $Z$ is binomial $(\lambda, 1)$. In fact, the author cited a reference for binomial distributions. But I do not see how this could transfer to Poisson distribution.

As far as I remember, it seems all these Chernoff type inequalities require the random variable under consideration being a sum of bounded random variables. So I am a bit suspicious of this inequality. Do you think it is still true for Poisson distribution?

Comment: A Poisson($\lambda$) variable is well approximated by a Binomial($n,\lambda/n$) variable with large $n$. The error in this approximation can be easily estimated.

Comment: Chernoff bounds can be seen as coming from an application of the Markov inequality to the MGF (and optimizing wrt the variable in the MGF), so I think it only requires the RV to have an MGF in some neighborhood of 0?

Comment: Chernoff bound doesn't require the random variable to be a sum of bounded random variables; there are conditions on the MGF though..

Comment: @jjjjjj I guess that's true, the MGF should be finite in a neighbourhood of $0$

Comment: Relevant: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~ccanonne/files/misc/2017-poissonconcentration.pdf

Comment: You should think of these inequalities of large deviation bounds. They give bounds of how unlikely it is that a random variable is further away from its mean than the standard deviation. Of course such bounds can hold for any family of distributions, not just those of independent repetitions. From this viewpoint, your inequality makes perfect sense. Inserting for $t$ the standard deviation $\lambda^{1/2}$ gives a bound that converges to a non zero number as $\lambda\to \infty$. Inserting any larger power of $\lambda$ gives a bound that converges to zero as $\lambda\to \infty$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may enjoy reading [this short note on Poisson tail bounds](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~ccanonne/files/misc/2017-poissonconcentration.pdf) (and references within).

Let $h\colon[-1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by $h(u)\stackrel{\rm def}{=} 2\frac{(1+u)\ln(1+u)-u}{u^2}$.

> **Theorem.** Let $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$, for some parameter $\lambda > 0$. Then, for any $x>0$, we have
>   $$
>     \mathbb{P}\left\{ X \geq \lambda + x \right\} \leq e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\lambda}h(\frac{x}{\lambda})}
> $$
>   and, for any $0<x< \lambda$,
>   \begin{equation}\label{eq:poisson:lower:tail}
>    \mathbb{P}\left\{ X \leq \lambda - x \right\} \leq e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\lambda}h({-\frac{x}{\lambda}})}.
> \end{equation}
>   In particular, this implies that $ \mathbb{P}\{ X \geq \lambda + x\},\mathbb{P}\{ X \leq \lambda - x\} \leq e^{-\frac{x^2}{\lambda+x}}$, for $x>0$; from which
>   \begin{equation}\label{eq:poisson:both:tail}
>   \mathbb{P}\{ \lvert{X -\lambda }\rvert \geq x \} \leq 2e^{-\frac{x^2}{2(\lambda+x)}}, \qquad x>0.
> \end{equation}

A proof (among others) can be found in the above document (also available on GitHub (with $\LaTeX$ source) [here](https://github.com/ccanonne/probabilitydistributiontoolbox/blob/master/poissonconcentration.pdf)).

The relevant reference is

> **[Pol15]** David Pollard. *MiniEmpirical*. http://www.stat.yale.edu/~pollard/Books/Mini/, 2015.
>   Manuscript (accessed 02-23-2017). 1, 1, 2, 0